# How to build a stable ABI wheel from the PEP517 build package?

Tags: python, c, packaging

### Context

I am currently developping a TreeSet/TreeMap package using an underlying C RedBlack tree library. I have developped a wrapper extension and in order to limit the number of binary wheels, I have used the stable ABI. To build the package distributions, I use `build` with a `pyproject.toml` configuration file, and `setuptools` as the backend.

### Problem

The command `python -m build` (or `pip install .`) can only build a wheel tagged `-cpxx-cpxx-platform` (eg `-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl` on Linux or `-0.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` on Windows). Using directly `setuptools` with a `setup.py` and a `setup.config` file, it is possible to build a wheel tagged as `cpxx-abi3-platform` with the command:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --py-limited-api=cpxx
```

but I could not find a way to pass the py-limited-api parameter to `build`

### Current config for a simplified example

###### `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=60.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "empty"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [
  { name="SBA", email="s-ball@laposte.net" },
]
description = "Simple demo"
readme = "README.md"
license = { file="LICENSE.txt" }
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Programming Language :: C",
]
```

###### `setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import os.path

kwargs = dict(
    # more metadata
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('empty.ext', [os.path.join('empty', 'ext.c')],
                  py_limited_api=True,
                  )]
)

setup(**kwargs)
```

###### `ext.c`

```c
#define Py_LIMITED_API 0x03070000

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>

// The module object
static PyObject* mod = NULL;

/*
 * Documentation for _rbtree.
 */
PyDoc_STRVAR(ext_doc, "Minimal extension module");

static PyObject *say_hello(PyObject *mod, PyObject *args) {
    return PyUnicode_FromString("Hello !");
}

PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"hello", &say_hello, METH_NOARGS, PyDoc_STR("Simple function")},
    {NULL},
};

static PyModuleDef ext_def = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "ext",
    ext_doc,
    -1,              /* m_size */
    .m_methods=methods,
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_ext() {
    mod = PyModule_Create(&ext_def);
    return mod;
}
```

and an empty `__init__.py` file to declare a normal package.

### Current research

I could not find anything about abi3 wheels anywhere in [build documentation](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), nor in the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) where only version tagged build packaging are documented.

### Workarounds

1. I could produce the expected wheels by manually unpacking a version tagged wheel (`wheel unpack ...whl`), changing its `RECORD` file, and packing it back (`wheel pack ...`)
2. Reverting to a good old `python setup.py ...` solution can directly build the correctly tagged wheel, but I am afraid that it is now legacy if not deprecated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is damned simple! The key is that if parameters cannot be passed (at least not simply) in the command line, they can be declared in config files. So here a simple solution is to add a `setup.cfg` with a `[build_wheel]` section:

```
[bdist_wheel]
py-limited-api=cp37
```

That is enough for the module in charge of the creation of the wheel to find its parameter and correctly build wheel tagged with `cp37-abi3-platform`